# How to search in a git repository for a string?

Tags: git, search

Is it possible to search in a given repository for a string (e.g. "class name")?

It would be useful for me even if it is a long time operation.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, see the "git grep" command